# Import zipdata (CSV) out of gmail into google spreadhseet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to built an google spreadsheet which automaticly imports the contents of  an attached .zip out of my gmail inbox (labeled test). I am absolutely no coder but I tried to copy paste some working bits of google script. I get an "invalid argument' error on line 26 (var extracted = Utilities.unzip(csv);)

Thnx in advance!

```
function getCSV() {


var query = "label:test";

var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
Logger.log('threads len ' + threads.length);

Logger.log(query);

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
Logger.log(messages);    
for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
   var supportStats = [];


var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
   Logger.log(msgs);
var attachments = msgs[0][0].getAttachments();
   Logger.log(attachments);



var csv =  attachments[0];
var extracted = Utilities.unzip(csv);
var string = extracted[0].getDataAsString(); //INVALID ARGUMENT ERROR
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(string);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("import");
sheet.clearContents();
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, data.length,data[0].length);
range.setValues(data);


}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, I thought that the blob of attachment file might have wrong mimeType (it's `application/x-zip` or others?) for using `Utilities.unzip()`. So how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var csv =  attachments[0];
```

To:

```
var csv =  attachments[0].setContentTypeFromExtension();
```

or

```
var csv =  attachments[0].setContentType("application/zip");
```

#### Note:

- From your script and question, this modification supposes that `attachments[0]` retrieved from `msgs[0][0].getAttachments()` is the blob of zip file. If this is not the zip file, please modify the script.

#### References:

- [setContentTypeFromExtension()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setContentTypeFromExtension())
- [setContentType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypecontenttype)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.